# Duplicate value when using unnest and joining table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to compare the data from 2 queries, one query have 3 tables using inner join and one table which has all the same data as the former 3 tables. However, when I use join on the 3 tables, I have more values than it should be. Here's my query.
This is query with 3 tables joining.

```
select 
b.date,
a.pagepath,
c.source,
c.medium,
b.pageviews,
count (b.pageviews) as count_pageview

from `traffic_sample_data` as c
inner join  `total_sample_data` as b
on c.fullVisitorId = b.fullVisitorId
inner join `hits_page_sample_data` as a 
on c.fullVisitorId = a.fullVisitorId

where a.pagepath = "/sellland"
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
    order by count_pageview desc
```

and this table contain all information of the previous 3 tables

```
select
date,
h.page.pagepath,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.source,
totals.pageviews,
count(totals.pageviews) as count_pageview

FROM `test-123.123.ga_sessions_20211117`,
unnest(hits) as h

where h.page.pagepath = "/sellland"
group by 1,2,3,4,5
order by count_pageview desc
```

I need help fixing the query as I get different result from 2 queries. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide data example of **all tables** and also and **example of the output** you want from **each query**.

Comment: Hello guys, apparently, I used subqueries and it worked. The problem is that these nested values have 2 or more nested layers, so using unnest just once does not work. Try using subquery and keep unnest up to the amount of layers the data has. @Wytrzymały Wiktor